# Как в Google Sheets прописать формулу высчитывающую дату первой пятницы до определенной даты?

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Как в Google Sheets прописать формулу высчитывающую дату первой пятницы до определенной даты?

Comment: точно так же, как и до любого другого дня недели: понедельника, вторника, среды, четверга, субботы или воскресенья. а начать надо с вычисления номера дня недели этой самой «определённой даты».